# Android Studio Install Disappears

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to install the latest Android Studio.

Environment:

Windows7 64-bit
JDK v12

I run the installer, and then it disappears after the initial setup progress dialog. Is there any way to troubleshoot this?

[Video of the install is here](https://youtu.be/y1ueVCxyhdo)

Comment: Did you check the task manager and see if the related installer services are still running? Sometimes they are just slow, like really slow. Also, I'm not sure if it'll help, but have you tried running it with Administrator privileges and see what happens?

Comment: Besides all that, you can try and download the non-exe version of Android Studio and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jackz314 for the original comment.  I used the zip version and found that my company has super agressive intrusion detection software that was terminating any flutter command line executions (and probably some commands run by the Android Studio installer).  I'll have to use a different machine as I don't want to go through the pain of sending a whitelist to IT